# elastic search query parsing exception when adding term filter

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm not quite sure why the term filter `"term": {"language": "Austrian"}` is causing an elastic search parse exception.

The surprising thing is it works if I remove the query_string query. 
Where would I put `"term": {"language": "Austrian"}` filter if it doesn't go there?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "status_type": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "7"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              [
                "name",
                "message"
              ]
            ],
            "query": "Arnold AND Schwarz"
          }
        },
        "term": {                <-- Causes parse exception
          "language": "Austrian"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `filter`, you need a [`bool` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) if you have more than one constraints, which is your case, since you have a [`query` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html) and a [`term` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html). So the correct way of doing it is like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "status_type": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "7"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {               <---- add this
          "must": [             <---- and this
            {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    [
                      "name",
                      "message"
                    ]
                  ],
                  "query": "Arnold AND Schwarz"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "language": "Austrian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if I may add something, I would rewrite your query a bit differently and move the `query_string` over to the `query` part and the `status_type` `term` over to the `filter` part, it would feel more "natural". Also, in your `query` part you don't need a `bool/must` if you have only one constraint.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            [
              "name",
              "message"
            ]
          ],
          "query": "Arnold AND Schwarz"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "status_type": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "7"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "language": "Austrian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "total": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you Val!